# How to disable single radio button on JSFX page?

Tags: oracle, jsp, jsf, jsp-tags, oracle-adf

I have a customer who created an Oracle ADF/JSF 1.1 application.  On one of the pages they have a table with first column as an enabled mutually exclusive radio buttons.  I had to enhance the page and add the total line with disabled radio button.  How can I disable it in Bean class or on the page without using JavaScript? I've tried to do something like:

```
<af:tableSelectOne id="slctone"  disabled="true"/>
```

but that disable all buttons.
I've tried to put the code like the one below, but that disables the link to next page on the second column:

```
TcpiVO t= (TcpiVO) JSFUtils.getManagedBeanValue("row");
if(t.getLabel().contains("TOTALS")){
    return false;
}
```

Here's the code snippet:

```
    <f:facet name="selection">
      <af:tableSelectOne id="slctone"  />
    </f:facet>

    <af:column sortable="false" headerText="#{tcWizard.partsHeaderLabel}"  width="325"  >

      <af:commandLink text="#{row.label}" action="#{tcWizard.retrieveDrillDownList}" actionListener="#{tcWizard.nextDrillDownElement}"
                      rendered="#{tcWizard.continueDrill }" id="drlLnk" />
      <af:outputText value="#{row.label}" rendered="#{!tcWizard.continueDrill }" />

    </af:column>
    <af:column sortable="false" headerText="#{msg.SALES}" styleClass="bordersBottomGrey"  width="80">
      <af:outputText value="#{row.sales}"/>
    </af:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I had to enhance the page and add the total line with disabled radio button. How can I disable it in Bean class or on the page without using JavaScript?*

Just make use of EL in the `disabled` attribute:

```
disabled="#{we are in the last row}"
```

This should return `true` when the mentioned condition is met.

Alternatively you can make use of a footer inside the table component:

```
<f:facet name="footer">
    ...
</f:facet>
```

This will generate a `<tfoot>` wherein you can place an independent row which would thus not be affected by other rows nor vice versa.